# Truly responsive content column with sidebar without media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, media

I am trying to make a responsive basic layout with a content-box (which has 3 columns) and a sidebar. The current problem I have is defining a margin on when the sidebar is on the right side and when the sidebar goes under the grid. Currently, I have no margin, but I would like to have 20px (for example) margin when the sidebar is on the right side and 50px when the sidebar is under the grid (or 20px so it is the same). Also `.sidebar` should be full width when on a new line. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0;">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .main {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                width: 100%;
                background: yellow;
            }
            .main .six-col {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
                display: grid;
                justify-content: space-between;
                column-gap: 15px;
                background: red;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
            }
            .main .six-col .col { border: 1px white solid;}
            .main .sidebar {
                flex: 0 0 250px;
                background: green;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="six-col">
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Can this be achieved without media queries?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Add negative margins to the `.main` container and positive margins to the children as follows:

```
.main {
    /* ... other stuff ... */
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.main > * {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This will give you margin when your `.sidebar` is not yet wrapped and when the `.sidebar` is wrapped.

- Furthermore you can add a flexbox attribute to make the wrapped `.sidebar` stretch across the whole width of the parent:

```css
.main .sidebar {
    /* ... other stuff ... */
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

So in total you would have the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0;">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .main {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                width: 100%;
                background: yellow;
                /* for spacing between sidebar and the six columns container */
                margin-top: -20px;
                margin-left: -20px;
            }
            .main > * {
                /* for spacing between sidebar and the six columns container */
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            .main .six-col {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
                display: grid;
                justify-content: space-between;
                column-gap: 15px;
                background: red;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
            }
            .main .six-col .col { border: 1px white solid;}
            .main .sidebar {
                flex: 0 0 250px;
                /* for stretching the wrapped sidebar */
                flex-grow: 1;
                background: green;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="six-col">
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Edit 1

I found a cleaner and easier solution using the `gap` property of "multi-column, flex, and grid layout" (see: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#gaps):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0;">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .super-main {
                margin: auto;
                max-width: 1200px;
                padding: 50px;
                background-color: #FFD700;
            }
            .main {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                width: 100%;
                background: yellow;
                row-gap: 15px;
                column-gap: 15px;
            }
            .main .six-col {
                flex-grow: 3;
                display: grid;
                justify-content: space-between;
                column-gap: 15px;
                background: red;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
            }
            .main .six-col .col {
                border: 1px white solid;
            }
            .main .sidebar {
                flex-basis: 250px;
                flex-shrink: 1;
                /* for stretching the wrapped sidebar */
                flex-grow: 1;
                background: green;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="super-main">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="six-col">
                    <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                    <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                    <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                    <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                    <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                    <div class="col">asdsad d asd asad ad sadas sad asd asd asd sad sad asd asd asd asd asd sad </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    sidebar
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is a good solution! Unfortunately it is currently supported on firefox and Chrome (Chromium) does not support flex gutters (row gap and column gap). I think we are getting closer to the true answer!

Comment: I have found the following solution better: https://jsfiddle.net/xnzkq2ms/3/